# Can't fix ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I'm building my own `PaginatorComponent`. I need to wrap that `PaginatorComponent` in my own, app based,  `MyPaginatorComponent`.
I'm getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is stackblitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f28v5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-paginator.component.ts

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wasn't too hard..

change line 47 of your paginator component from `this.currentPage = 1;` to `this._currentPage = 1;`

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple timeout will resolve your issue : [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyddrv?file=src/app/my-paginator.component.ts)

```
onPageChange(page: number) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.current = page;
    this.page.emit(page);
  });
}
```

If you want to find your issue, you will have to see where you set the current page (because the error clearly states that the current page is the issue), and check if it isn't changed multiple times during the lifecycle.

I'm going to look it up for you too, but for now, you can resolve your issue with this.

**EDIT** Your error comes from this peice of code :

```
@Input() set pageSize(i: number) {
  this._pageSize = i;
  this.currentPage = 1;
  this.calculatePages();
}
```

You have to not use the getter, and directly the private property, `_currentPage`.

Comment: As the asnwer describes, a timeout will easily fix the error visually but doesn't resolve the root of the problem. ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError means that a variable has being changed twice in the same update cycle. a timeout will delay one of the variable updates resulting in hiding the error. See my answer for a simple solution.